# Vimscript append string at line and column

Tags: ruby, vim

I'm new to vim and vimscript and getting my head with all this.

I'm trying to write a plugin that replicates the behaviour of [VVDocumenter](https://github.com/onevcat/VVDocumenter-Xcode) for ruby code, so, if the cursor is over a method for example and activates the plugin, it should build a skeleton to document it.

For example this code:

```
def method1(obj1, obj2)
  // Code
end
```

should generate this comments:

```
#
#
# @param [] obj1
# @param [] obj2
# @return []
def method1(obj1, obj2)
  // Code
end
```

I'am having trouble inserting the completion in the correct column, at the same level where def is defined.

Any help will be great!

Thanks

Comment: if you find something like that for vim or other ide - please, let me know!

Comment: @skywinder I have impemented a very simple plugin that just works for ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work around `range` and `ex` insert in `normal` mode, something like below:

```
1 def foo(params)
2  // code
3 end
```

When in `normal` mode:

```
:0,4:normal O# @param [] obj1
```

`Vim` do:

```
1 # @param [] obj1
2 # @param [] obj1
3 # @param [] obj1
4 # @param [] obj1
5 # @param [] obj1
6 def foo(params)
7  // code
8 end
```

Explain `:0,4:normal O# @param [] obj1` - from `0` to `4` line, insert in `normal` mode `O`(puts before `0` line) this text `# @param [] obj1`.

Put this in function(not sure, can't test now):

```
function! PutComments()
  for lineno in range(a:firstline, a:lastline)
    exec ":normal O# @param [] obj1"
  endfor
endfunction
```

Comment: Can i execute this with variables inside a vimscript ?

Comment: yep, you can execute any function in normal mode by `exe[cute]` http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#:execute.

Comment: Something like this should work `exec "=start,=end:normal 0# Methods Description"` ?

Comment: What is 0 doing here ? I need to start the comment at the same level as def. In the example def is two spaces after 0.

Comment: `O` - enter to insert mode before cursor. `:normal O   ` insert 4 space before cursor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57621/discussion-between-bilby91-and-).